# Can callback function can be next line of code

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, onload

```
Code:

     var getImageFromUrl = function(url, callback) {
      var img = new Image();

      img.onError = function() {
        alert('Cannot load image: "'+url+'"');
      };
      img.onload = function() {
        callback(img);
      };
      img.src = url;
    }
 getImageFromUrl(somurl, Nextline);
LINE1-//should come here  after callback(img)
```

I wanted that after img.onload function the compiler will run code in line1

Comment: no... because those callbacks are executed asynchronously

Comment: you are never firing those functions inside only declaring them...

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can do this using JQuery Callback function.

```
var getImageFromUrl = function(url, callback) {
  var img = new Image();

  img.onError = function() {
    alert('Cannot load image: "'+url+'"');
  };
  img.onload = function() {
    callback(img);
  };
  img.src = url;
}
var callBack = $.Callbacks();
callBack.add(getImageFromUrl(somurl, Nextline));
callBack.add(function(){
  // LINE 1 logic can be executed here.
 });

callBack.fire();
```

For further reference, please refer to  [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.callbacks/)

Comment: And, how does this make it so the Line 1 logic is executed after Nextline is called?